# Custom style for dynamically generated ProgressBars/Widgets

Tags: android, android-widget, android-progressbar, android-styles

How do I create a custom horizontal ProgressBar style using styles.xml and then utilize it when I create a ProgressBar like so:

```
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(this, null, ???)
```

All the tutorials I've seen focus on attaching the style when the widget is defined in the XML layout, which is not what I need.  I've tried mixing tutorials but I get lost when I try to call up my style via android.R, and the method by which you modify styles seems to be different depending on where in the code you do it.

Basically I want to do this:

http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/#comment-203

in styles.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I wanted was a Drawable.

This helped: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html

And then later I found this, which also helped: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html

I customized an XML file in a new folder I created: res/drawable/custombar.xml, then customized it like the site had it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners 
                android:radius="5dip"
            />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
                <gradient
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:endColor="#ff009900"
                    android:startColor="#ff000099" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
```

And then set it to the ProgressBar in my Activity like so:

```
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal);
bar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar));
```

Hopefully this helps some people out.